# Set CornerRadius of CheckBox in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I have an application that allows multiple selection of items in the UI with checkboxes. The thing is checkboxes are generated from a file because the company adds or removes selections from the search.

Since I read a file to get all the possible selections available, the checkbox is generated in C# code, not XAML and one requirement for the UI is to have rounded checkboxes. How can I achieve this in C#?

I did this in XAML:

```
<CheckBox Content="QA Standard" IsEnabled="{Binding CanEdit, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      ToolTip="{Binding StatusInfo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      BorderBrush="{Binding StatusColor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      BorderThickness="2"
      Margin="5" >
<CheckBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="12" />
    </Style>
</CheckBox.Resources>
```

Tried to redo it in C# but doesn't seems to work:

```
CheckBox c = new CheckBox() { BorderThickness = new Thickness(2), Content = b, Margin = new Thickness(5) };

var enabled = new Binding() { Source = DataContext, Path = new PropertyPath("CanEdit"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged };
var tooltip = new Binding() { Source = DataContext, Path = new PropertyPath("StatusInfo"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged };
var border = new Binding() { Source = DataContext, Path = new PropertyPath("StatusColor"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged };              

BindingOperations.SetBinding( c, CheckBox.IsEnabledProperty, enabled );
BindingOperations.SetBinding( c, CheckBox.ToolTipProperty, tooltip );
BindingOperations.SetBinding( c, CheckBox.BorderBrushProperty, border );

var cStyle = new Style( typeof(Border) );
cStyle.Setters.Add( new Setter( Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new CornerRadius( 12.0 ) ) );
c.Resources.Add( "CornerRadiusBorder", cStyle );

Boxes.Children.Add( c );
```

Comment: Use an ItemsControl with an appropriate ItemTemplate to dynamically generate the CheckBoxes. Creating UI elements in code behind is hardly ever necessary.

Comment: @mm8 Yes, in XAML it works, but when I translate this to C# and quit the XAML it show everything exactly the same except the corners

Comment: @mm8 Windows 10 @_@

Comment: @Clemens I'll check that

Comment: I was trying the ItemsControl template approach but seems to break the application's MVVM since I have to add more code in XAML and create a new class to host the items properties and didn't know how to bind the properties from the template to the already existing context. All checkboxes bind to the same properties except the IsChecked. Decided to got for mm8 answer

Comment: MVVM is very much about not creating UI in code behind. You should continue your effort. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: I know, thanks. Got it working with ItemsControl, despite I had to search for binding to relative ancestor's DataContext(: But it's fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the key of the resource:

```
var cStyle = new Style(typeof(Border));
cStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new CornerRadius(12.0)));
c.Resources.Add(typeof(Border), cStyle);
```

Comment: Excellent! Thought key was a unique name, not the type. This works perfectly!